# template class and using overloaded constructor with mixed parameters in c++

Tags: c++, templates

For my constructor and overloaded constructor definitions I have:

```
template <class T> Student<T>::Student(){}
template <class T> Student<T>::Student(string sName, int sAge) {
    m_name = sName;
    m_age = sAge;
}
```

I am getting confused on how to call a constructor with mixed parameters in the overloaded constructor.
My understanding is that if they were both ints I would do something like:

```
Student <int> newStudent;
newStudent(10, 15);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Student<int>` is a type.  `Student<int> newStudent;` creates a variable of that type, which means it is **constructing** that object.  Since no arguments are included, the no-argument constructor is used.

`newStudent(10, 15)` is the attempting to call an `::operator()(int, int)` member of that class, which may or may not be defined.

You probably want:

```
Student<int> newStudent("Mary", 15);
```

... to create a `Student<int>` type object in the variable `newStudent`.